# Create a constant in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Suppose that I have this query:

```
select * 
from myTable
where myTable.myCol in (1,2,3)
```

I would like to do that:

```
with allowed_values as (1,2,3)
select * 
from myTable
where myTable.myCol in allowed_values
```

It gives me a Syntax Error in the first row, can you help me fixing it?

Comment: What you've written uses "allowed_values" as if it were a variable. It's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close to what you probably had in mind:

```
WITH allowed_values AS (SELECT '{1,2,3}'::int[] AS arr)
SELECT * 
FROM   my_table
      ,allowed_values   -- cross join with a single row
WHERE  my_col = ANY (arr);
```

Better:

```
WITH allowed_values (my_col) AS (VALUES (1), (2), (3))
SELECT * 
FROM   allowed_values
JOIN   my_table USING (my_col)
```

But really, you can just simplify:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS allowed_values (my_col)
JOIN   my_table USING (my_col);
```

Comment: You got the point in the first one. "1,2,3" is a string that comes from a text field: I could tokenize it, but it is to complicate for the purpose that I have in mind! Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The closest I can think to your syntax:

```
WITH allowed_values (id) AS 
  ( VALUES
      (1), (2), (3)
  )
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE id IN 
   (TABLE allowed_values) ;
```

Tested in **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/83694/1)**

Comment: That's interesting. I wouldn't have thought the `table allowed_values` works in a sub-select.

Comment: Table constructor in the WHERE clause. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall': It's just a [syntactical shortcut for `(SELECT * FROM allowed_values)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-TABLE).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: That explains why I couldn't find it by looking for table constructors.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
with allowed_values as (select 1 as tst union all select 2 union all select 3)    
select * from myTable a
inner join c1 b ON (b.tst = a.myCol)
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way forward is to correct your common table expression, then use it in a subselect.

```
with allowed_values as (
  select 1 id
  union all
  select 2
  union all
  select 3
)
select * from myTable
where myTable.id in (select id from allowed_values)
```